# Remove dublicate rows in long table using matlab

Tags: matlab, unique

I have a table (800027x10) with column 1 containing timestamps of which some are identical like so

```
0
1
2
3 data0
3 data1
4
5
6 data2
6 data3
```

i would like to remove the double timestamps although they might contain other data in the other columns. After removing it should look like this

```
0
1
2
3 data0
4
5
6 data2
```

I checked the amount of double entrys

```
for i=1:height(tablePos)-1
     timeDiff = tablePos.TimestampNs(i+1)-tablePos.TimestampNs(i);
    if timeDiff == 0
        counterTimeDiff = counterTimeDiff +1;
    end
end
```

Which results in 11319

but when i use

```
[~,idu] = unique(tablePos(:,1),'stable');
uniquerows = tablePos(idu,:);
```

i get a table with only  686837 instead of 800027-11319=‭788708‬. What am i doing wrong.

Table is timestamp sorted btw. Also trying

```
tablePos1 = tablePos
for i=1:height(tablePos)-1
     timeDiff = tablePos.TimestampNs(i+1)-tablePos.TimestampNs(i);
     if timeDiff == 0
         tablePos1(i,:) = [];
     end
end
```

does not work as this takes forever

I just realized that there is only a power of ten difference 11319 compared to 113190, which i cannot explain

Comment: Could you provide tablePos1 dataset?

Comment: Yes i can. Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ibj75cn5lfi3foo/TablePos.csv?dl=0

Comment: Your `unique` solution is correct. I guess your count of duplicates is incorrect because you didn’t initialize `counterTimeDiff` to zero. Another possible reason for discrepancy is that the timestamps are not all sorted.

Comment: In that case there is some serious problem with the system. My matlab skills aren't good. Any good way to test this? Some histogram plot that counts occurences of timestamps?

Comment: What do you mean a serious problem? Time stamps not being sorted? You can easily check that with `any(diff(timestamps)<0)`. `unique` will give you all unique elements, the size of its output is the number of unique elements.

Comment: I meant that the origin of data would have a serious problem then. Anyway `any(diff(tablePos.TimestampNs)<0)` return 0. And so does `[a,b] = histcounts(tablePos.TimestampNs,unique(tablePos.TimestampNs));
counterTimeDiff1 = 0;
counterTimeDiff2 = 0;
for i=1:size(a)
    if a(i) == 2
        counterTimeDiff1 = counterTimeDiff1 +1;
    end
    if a(i) > 2
        counterTimeDiff2 = counterTimeDiff2 +1;
    end 
end` also return 0 for both counters.

Comment: OK. Another thing to check is that `tablePos.TimestampNs` really is the same as `tablePos(:,1)`.

Comment: What is the type of that column anyway? Is it double floats or some integer kind?

Comment: I guess it is the same the first column of `tablePos` contains the timestamp which is named `TimestampNs` so it should be the same as `tablePos(:,1)` shouldn't it? Datatype of that column would be 64bit unsigned integer

Comment: Ah! There is your problem. Subtracting two unsigned integers always yields a value >=0. Convert to double and then check if the `diff` returns any negative values.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i used `any(diff(tablePos.TimestampNs)> 605290133699071800)` now as this is the biggest timestamp and subtracting unsigned which results in less than zero should lead to some big u64 value. This test results in 0. So i really hope data is sorted. Which still leaves the odd power of ten difference in the unique approach. But the solution with indices saving works perfectly

Comment: No, MATLAB uses saturated arithmetic. With unsigned units, 1-10==0. One thing you can do is flip the array and see if there are any positive differences: `any(diff(flip(timestamps))>0)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo okay understood. Leads to one. Checked these indices manually. There is a difference ... so apperently you discovered an even bigger problem. Have to look into that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds painful, sorry. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

When two successive elements are the same you should not increase the checking index i. You should keep the old one for the next checking. Here you just can update i as i = i-1

```
tablePos1 = tablePos
for i=1:height(tablePos)-1
     timeDiff = tablePos.TimestampNs(i+1)-tablePos.TimestampNs(i);
     if timeDiff == 0
         tablePos1(i,:) = [];
         i = i -1;
     end
end
```

This is similar to the illustration below

```
    x = [0 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6];
    i = 1;
    while(i<length(x))

        if x(i+1) == x(i)
            x(i+1) =[];
        else
            i = i+1;
        end

     end
```

## Result

```
x = [ 0     1     2     3     4     5     6]
```

Comment: This is what i did in the first place (see end of my post). Unfortunatly on large datasets this seems to take forever

Comment: No they are different, when two successive elements are the same you should not increase the checking index i. You should keep the old one for the next checking

Comment: Okay i see why you are doing this. Nevertheless this soultion is not feasable as it takes forever to run aperently

Comment: You would speed this up humongously by keeping a list of indices to keep or to delete, and indexing into the array after the loop. Repeatedly deleting an element is very expensive.

Comment: I understand the first part. What execatly do you mean by 'indexing into the array'?

Comment: @Dennis: The same as what you do with your `unique` solution. Also, add `@cris` to your comment if you want me to be notified of it. This is necessary anytime when the person you reply to is not the author of the question or answer you are commenting under.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Cheers. Saving the indices and after copying the table worked like a charm. Now i get the expected result. Still leaves the question if the table really isn't sorted which i will try to test now.